# Why I can't set android-platform lower then 22 when I compile?

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

When I compile standard hello world project, created by cocos-console (`cocos2d-x 3.6`) with `--ap android-16` (android platform 16) it wrights:

```
The android-platform of project "E:\projects\cocos_projects\test\proj.android" s
hould be equal/larger than 22, but 16 is specified.
```

In AndroidManifest.xml I have: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>`.

In SDK manager I have installed all platforms and at `...\sdk\platforms` I have 8, 10, 15-22 and MNC folders.

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Comment: ye, below - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31092377/5056618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrey answer is basically right, but I'll complete it with some missing information for the sake of any other cocos2d-x developers looking for how to solve this.

This error:

> The android-platform of project
>   "E:\projects\cocos_projects\test\proj.android" should be equal/larger
>   than 22, but 16 is specified.

appears when you tell to the `cocos` command to use an Android API version (`--ap android-XX`) which conflicts with your `project properties` configuration.

Let's say your `proj.android/project.properties` is something like this:

```
target=android-22
android.library.reference.1=../cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/java
```

So, before launching a command that request to use a different Android API version (ex. `cocos compile -p android --ap android-16`), you should manually edit `project.properties` and changed the `target` key to a value that matches the new Android API version you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

when i modify `...\proj.android\project.properties` it works

Comment: I found an answer - In addition to setting project properties, I set targetSDK, and APPLICATION PLATFORM. Then it works.